# Confused with textbook problem (Questioning if it is even correct)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

[Textbook Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my1vf.png)

The provided textbook problem states that the new volume is calculated to be 2, however, I calculated the new volume to be 5/2. Could someone fact-check that the answer is 2 and explain why that is? Please and thank you.

Comment: How did you get $\frac52$?

Comment: When I went to find the base and height of the transformed figure, I got sqrt(5) for the base and sqrt(5)/2 for the height, while the textbook got the same base for 2sqrt(5)/5 for the height.

Comment: It sounds like you interpreted "base" and "height" as "the two sides", but the area of a parallelogram is not the product of its two sides. If the base is $\sqrt 5$, then the height is the perpendicular distance between the two sides of length $\sqrt 5$.

Comment: Ah, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new volume is definitely $2$. Here is a quick way to see that:

[image: the volume is 2]

Here, $\mathcal T(C_2)$ is divided into four triangles that each have area $\frac12$ (for example, because viewed sideways they have a base of length $1$ and an altitude of length $1$).